# Find unique column value from records where another column has ALL of the values from a set

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Let's say I have a table like this:

```
+----+-------+
| ID | Word  |
+----+-------+
|  1 | a     |
|  1 | dog   |
|  1 | has   |
|  2 | two   |
|  2 | three |
|  2 | four  |
|  2 | five  |
|  3 | black |
|  3 | red   |
+----+-------+
```

I want to find the unique `ID` value where there are records with that `ID` that have *all* of the `Word` values in a provided set.  E.g. `WHERE Word IN ('a', 'dog', 'has')` would return `ID` value `1` but `WHERE Word IN ('a', 'dog', 'has', 'black')` would return `NULL`.

Is this possible?

Comment: Anything is possible, so yes.

Comment: @dfundako  nope.

Comment: Can a word be repeated within an `Id` group, e.g. could `42` have two `dog`s? Dr Linoff's answer, based on the sample data, appears to assume that the words are unique within a group.

Comment: @HABO -- Yes, thanks for pointing that out.  Words can be duplicate in a group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `group by` and `having`:

```
select id
from t
where word in ('a', 'dog', 'has')
group by id
having count(*) = 3;  - the number of words in the list
```

Comment: Regarding HABO's comment.... if dupes are possible, use "having count(distinct word) = 3"

Comment: @KevinSuchlicki -- Can you clarify?  what is "distinct word" representing?  There can be multiple words, some or all of which can be distinct.

Comment: @rory.ap . . . Are `id`/`word` pairs repeated in the table?

Comment: Yes they are repeated in the table unless I can figure out an efficient way to de-dupe.

Comment: I figure it out.  Just needed a simple `DISTINCT` in the query that populates the word tabled!  Duh!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SQL 2016 or higher this seems like a good solution:

```
--Load test data
DECLARE @tbl as TABLE (id int, word varchar(40))
INSERT INTO @tbl
(id, word)
VALUES
(1, 'a'),(1,'dog'),(1,'cat'),(1,'has'),(1,'a'),(2,'two'),(2,'three'),(2,'four'),(2,'five'),(3,'black'),(3,'red')

--ACTUAL SOLUTION STARTS HERE
DECLARE @srch as VARCHAR(200)
SET @srch = 'a,dog,has'

SELECT id 
FROM @tbl
WHERE word IN (SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@srch,','))
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT word) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT value) FROM STRING_SPLIT(@srch,','));
```